# Install OpenDR in CentOS 7 for native Python 3 (not Anaconda Python)

Tags: linux, installation, centos, python, render

The following command didn't work. Could you please guide me on how to fix it?

```
$ pip install opendr
Collecting opendr
  Downloading opendr-0.78.tar.gz (581 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 581 kB 1.3 MB/s 
Requirement already satisfied: Cython in /scratch3/venv/frank/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from opendr) (0.29.22)
Requirement already satisfied: chumpy>=0.58 in /scratch3/venv/frank/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from opendr) (0.70)
Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib in /scratch3/venv/frank/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from opendr) (3.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=0.13.0 in /scratch3/venv/frank/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from chumpy>=0.58->opendr) (1.6.2)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.11.0 in /scratch3/venv/frank/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from chumpy>=0.58->opendr) (1.15.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy<1.23.0,>=1.16.5 in /scratch3/venv/frank/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from scipy>=0.13.0->chumpy>=0.58->opendr) (1.20.2)
Requirement already satisfied: kiwisolver>=1.0.1 in /scratch3/venv/frank/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from matplotlib->opendr) (1.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing>=2.2.1 in /scratch3/venv/frank/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from matplotlib->opendr) (2.4.7)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.7 in /scratch3/venv/frank/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from matplotlib->opendr) (2.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: cycler>=0.10 in /scratch3/venv/frank/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from matplotlib->opendr) (0.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pillow>=6.2.0 in /scratch3/venv/frank/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from matplotlib->opendr) (8.1.2)
Building wheels for collected packages: opendr
  Building wheel for opendr (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /scratch3/venv/frank/bin/python3.8 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/scratch/tmp/pip-install-2xl2_aae/opendr_cca5ff679db14567af924447cc43444b/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/scratch/tmp/pip-install-2xl2_aae/opendr_cca5ff679db14567af924447cc43444b/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /scratch/tmp/pip-wheel-xb1f2chh
       cwd: /scratch/tmp/pip-install-2xl2_aae/opendr_cca5ff679db14567af924447cc43444b/
  Complete output (65 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/opendr
  copying opendr/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/opendr
  copying opendr/camera.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/opendr
  copying opendr/common.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/opendr
  copying opendr/cvwrap.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/opendr
  copying opendr/dummy.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/opendr
  copying opendr/everything.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/opendr
  copying opendr/filters.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/opendr
  copying opendr/geometry.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/opendr
  copying opendr/lighting.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/opendr
  copying opendr/occlusion_test.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/opendr
  copying opendr/renderer.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/opendr
  copying opendr/serialization.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/opendr
  copying opendr/simple.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/opendr
  copying opendr/slider_demo.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/opendr
  copying opendr/test_camera.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/opendr
  copying opendr/test_depth_renderer.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/opendr
  copying opendr/test_geometry.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/opendr
  copying opendr/test_renderer.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/opendr
  copying opendr/test_sh.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/opendr
  copying opendr/topology.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/opendr
  copying opendr/util_tests.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/opendr
  copying opendr/utils.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/opendr
  copying opendr/version.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/opendr
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/opendr/contexts
  copying opendr/contexts/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/opendr/contexts
  copying opendr/contexts/_constants.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/opendr/contexts
  copying opendr/contexts/autogen.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/opendr/contexts
  copying opendr/contexts/draw_triangle_shaders_2_1.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/opendr/contexts
  copying opendr/contexts/draw_triangle_shaders_3_2.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/opendr/contexts
  copying opendr/contexts/fix_warnings.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/opendr/contexts
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/opendr/test_dr
  copying opendr/test_dr/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/opendr/test_dr
  running build_ext
  building 'opendr.contexts.ctx_mesa' extension
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/opendr
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/opendr/contexts
  gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -D__OSMESA__=1 -Iopendr/contexts -I. -I/scratch3/venv/frank/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/include -Iopendr/contexts/OSMesa/include -I/scratch3/venv/frank/include -I/usr/local/include/python3.8 -c opendr/contexts/ctx_mesa.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/opendr/contexts/ctx_mesa.o -lstdc++
  In file included from /scratch3/venv/frank/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:1944:0,
                   from /scratch3/venv/frank/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:12,
                   from /scratch3/venv/frank/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/arrayobject.h:4,
                   from opendr/contexts/ctx_mesa.c:660:
  /scratch3/venv/frank/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h:17:2: warning: #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with " "#define NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION" [-Wcpp]
   #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with " \
    ^~~~~~~
  opendr/contexts/ctx_mesa.c: In function ‘__pyx_pf_6opendr_8contexts_8ctx_mesa_13OsContextBase_150ShaderSource’:
  opendr/contexts/ctx_mesa.c:13144:49: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘glShaderSource’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
     glShaderSource(__pyx_v_shader, __pyx_v_count, (&__pyx_v_s), (&__pyx_v_len));
                                                   ^
  In file included from opendr/contexts/OSMesa/include/GL/gl.h:2085:0,
                   from opendr/contexts/gl_includes.h:10,
                   from opendr/contexts/ctx_mesa.c:668:
  opendr/contexts/OSMesa/include/GL/glext.h:5794:21: note: expected ‘const GLchar ** {aka const char **}’ but argument is of type ‘char **’
   GLAPI void APIENTRY glShaderSource (GLuint shader, GLsizei count, const GLchar* *string, const GLint *length);
                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  gcc -pthread -shared build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/opendr/contexts/ctx_mesa.o -Lopendr/contexts/OSMesa/lib -lOSMesa -lGL -lGLU -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/opendr/contexts/ctx_mesa.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so -lstdc++
  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lOSMesa
  collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
  error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for opendr
  Running setup.py clean for opendr
Failed to build opendr
Installing collected packages: opendr
    Running setup.py install for opendr ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /scratch3/venv/frank/bin/python3.8 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/scratch/tmp/pip-install-2xl2_aae/opendr_cca5ff679db14567af924447cc43444b/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/scratch/tmp/pip-install-2xl2_aae/opendr_cca5ff679db14567af924447cc43444b/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /scratch/tmp/pip-record-q52my77n/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /scratch3/venv/frank/include/site/python3.8/opendr
         cwd: /scratch/tmp/pip-install-2xl2_aae/opendr_cca5ff679db14567af924447cc43444b/
    Complete output (65 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/opendr
    copying opendr/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/opendr
    copying opendr/camera.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/opendr
    copying opendr/common.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/opendr
    copying opendr/cvwrap.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/opendr
    copying opendr/dummy.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/opendr
    copying opendr/everything.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/opendr
    copying opendr/filters.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/opendr
    copying opendr/geometry.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/opendr
    copying opendr/lighting.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/opendr
    copying opendr/occlusion_test.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/opendr
    copying opendr/renderer.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/opendr
    copying opendr/serialization.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/opendr
    copying opendr/simple.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/opendr
    copying opendr/slider_demo.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/opendr
    copying opendr/test_camera.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/opendr
    copying opendr/test_depth_renderer.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/opendr
    copying opendr/test_geometry.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/opendr
    copying opendr/test_renderer.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/opendr
    copying opendr/test_sh.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/opendr
    copying opendr/topology.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/opendr
    copying opendr/util_tests.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/opendr
    copying opendr/utils.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/opendr
    copying opendr/version.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/opendr
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/opendr/contexts
    copying opendr/contexts/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/opendr/contexts
    copying opendr/contexts/_constants.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/opendr/contexts
    copying opendr/contexts/autogen.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/opendr/contexts
    copying opendr/contexts/draw_triangle_shaders_2_1.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/opendr/contexts
    copying opendr/contexts/draw_triangle_shaders_3_2.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/opendr/contexts
    copying opendr/contexts/fix_warnings.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/opendr/contexts
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/opendr/test_dr
    copying opendr/test_dr/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/opendr/test_dr
    running build_ext
    building 'opendr.contexts.ctx_mesa' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/opendr
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/opendr/contexts
    gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -D__OSMESA__=1 -Iopendr/contexts -I. -I/scratch3/venv/frank/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/include -Iopendr/contexts/OSMesa/include -I/scratch3/venv/frank/include -I/usr/local/include/python3.8 -c opendr/contexts/ctx_mesa.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/opendr/contexts/ctx_mesa.o -lstdc++
    In file included from /scratch3/venv/frank/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:1944:0,
                     from /scratch3/venv/frank/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:12,
                     from /scratch3/venv/frank/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/arrayobject.h:4,
                     from opendr/contexts/ctx_mesa.c:660:
    /scratch3/venv/frank/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h:17:2: warning: #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with " "#define NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION" [-Wcpp]
     #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with " \
      ^~~~~~~
    opendr/contexts/ctx_mesa.c: In function ‘__pyx_pf_6opendr_8contexts_8ctx_mesa_13OsContextBase_150ShaderSource’:
    opendr/contexts/ctx_mesa.c:13144:49: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘glShaderSource’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
       glShaderSource(__pyx_v_shader, __pyx_v_count, (&__pyx_v_s), (&__pyx_v_len));
                                                     ^
    In file included from opendr/contexts/OSMesa/include/GL/gl.h:2085:0,
                     from opendr/contexts/gl_includes.h:10,
                     from opendr/contexts/ctx_mesa.c:668:
    opendr/contexts/OSMesa/include/GL/glext.h:5794:21: note: expected ‘const GLchar ** {aka const char **}’ but argument is of type ‘char **’
     GLAPI void APIENTRY glShaderSource (GLuint shader, GLsizei count, const GLchar* *string, const GLint *length);
                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    gcc -pthread -shared build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/opendr/contexts/ctx_mesa.o -Lopendr/contexts/OSMesa/lib -lOSMesa -lGL -lGLU -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/opendr/contexts/ctx_mesa.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so -lstdc++
    /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lOSMesa
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /scratch3/venv/frank/bin/python3.8 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/scratch/tmp/pip-install-2xl2_aae/opendr_cca5ff679db14567af924447cc43444b/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/scratch/tmp/pip-install-2xl2_aae/opendr_cca5ff679db14567af924447cc43444b/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /scratch/tmp/pip-record-q52my77n/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /scratch3/venv/frank/include/site/python3.8/opendr Check the logs for full command output.
```

I have:

```
$ python
Python 3.8.5 (default, Mar 31 2021, 02:37:07) 
[GCC 7.3.1 20180303 (Red Hat 7.3.1-5)] on linux
```

and

```
$ lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    :core-4.1-amd64:core-4.1-noarch
Distributor ID: CentOS
Description:    CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core)
Release:    7.9.2009
Codename:   Core
```

Comment: [`opendr` only lists Python 2 support on PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/opendr/). So you likely need a virtual environment with Python 2.7 at the very least (excluding any other potential issues).

Comment: I need to install it for Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, [the latest version of opendr listed on PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/opendr/) (where `pip` pulls files from) is version 0.78. This version only lists Python 2 as being supported, while you are using Python 3. The most direct route to installing opendr would be to create a Python virtual environment with e.g. Python 2.7 and install opendr in that environment (setting aside any other potential issues).

> I need to install opendr for Python 3.

Then you will likely wish to Google something like "[opendr python 3](https://www.google.com/search?q=opendr+python+3)". This returns results such as [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/mattloper/opendr/issues/19) and [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/akanazawa/hmr/issues/82) which discuss the topic. In short, there seems to be at least one method to install opendr with some additional software packages (CentOS is not directly discussed), while the other option is to install a fork of the project.

**Listed Forks (Python 3)**

- [opendr (GitHub - fork from polmorenoc)](https://github.com/polmorenoc/opendr)
- [opendr (GitHub - fork from SelvamArul)](https://github.com/SelvamArul/opendr)

---

*As a minor note, it appears that the OSMesa API may be a sticking point. It is indirectly referenced in both GitHub issues above, [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64969585/not-able-to-install-opendr-in-python-3-6-error-in-visual-studio-libs) and your own error output.*